# Deleting a post should not interrupt my reading

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, live-refresh

Recently I came across a ~15 lines question. Somehow the question became deleted while I was reading it halfway through. I know that because the text became white and a popup appeared telling me that the question had become deleted. So the information was clear: the question is now deleted.

However I was clearly interrupted while reading the question to make the question not readable. At that point, I don't care that the question is deleted. So don't interrupt me by making me unable to finish reading it: just tell me I can't answer or whatever because the question has become deleted meanwhile. Don't force me into interrupting my reading.

Take example from the behavior of an edited question: it's simple, just a tad intrusive but it's 1000 times better than the behavior of a deleted question.

Note, thanks to my dear <kbd>F12</kbd> key and some CSS knowledge, I could finish reading the question.

Comment: The point of this feature is to keep you from wasting your time. Why finish reading if you can't actually post an answer? *"At that point, I don't care that the question is deleted."* You should, it's an extremely important change to the status of the question.

Comment: @meagar You can inform the reader that the post is deleted without making it impossible to read the post at all.  For example, by graying it out, as you do with heavily downvoted posts, or by adding a banner above or below a post, rather than *on top of* the post.  Or, for that matter, by just having a popup that can be dismissed if the user wants to keep reading  post that they know is deleted.

Comment: But again, **why** continue reading?

Comment: @meagar Perhaps the post should be undeleted.  Perhaps the post is going to be undeleted later (sometimes people delete a question/answer with the intention of editing it and undeleting).

Comment: @Servy Then you can (as a 10k+ user) reload the page, and interact with the deleted content, casting your undelete votes etc. A 5k user isn't *supposed* to be able to see deleted content; they can't interact with it in any way. Reloading the page will result in a 404. So, why could they possibly want to continue reading the question?

Comment: @meagar But that's *really* annoying.  It makes you lose your place in the post as you're reading, etc.  Why go so far out of your way to intentionally be disruptive, when you could just not go out of your way to be so disruptive.  What problem is this solving?

Comment: The question is not "why continue reading?" but "why do you want to decide in my place if I should stop reading?"

Comment: This is a semi-new feature as I have only noticed this recently.  Was there a meta post that discussed the implementation of this feature.  I'm very curious to understand the "problem" that was solved with this, rather than the old notification via a banner.

Comment: Also, why do you try so hard to make sure I can't read the question?

Comment: I think OP should have used the phrase "should not prevent" as opposed to "should not interrupt"

Comment: Even though I have 10k+ rep, I still want this feature. It's just frustrating to refresh long spam/offensive posts and then click on revision history.

Comment: Does this also apply to self-deletions?  I know it's not the main workflow, but deleting your own post shouldn't miscommunicate that deletion is the same as drowning a post in white-out.  10k users (and the author in the case of self-deletion) can still see all the details when reloaded.  Just apply the regular deleted post styling instead of that awful whiteout.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the devs slapping a button below the notice that'd do the CSS work of changing back the opacity and removing the banner for me.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Although I can't cite any specific meta posts, the complaint was that some poor user spent time writing an answer, and only after finishing discovered that the question had been deleted. The banner at the top can go unnoticed until it's too late.

Comment: @meagar As a 10K user, this new feature doesn't bother me, in fact I kinda like the way it works now. But that's because I can just reload the page and continue reading the now-deleted post. Why continue reading? It's simple human curiosity. I started reading, and even if the question is a train wreck, I want to know how the story ends. Then I can have a chuckle and get on with my life.

Comment: As a (probably temporary) workaround, you can use HTTPS Everywhere.  Then the page won't refresh while you're reading it.

Comment: @meagar I think your comment would qualify as a answer. If an user with 5k rep **can't** see deleted content then the feature is well placed. You remove his *right/permission* to access the content as soon as possible. There's no *why* to answer. Why? Because an user with your reputation can't access this content. Simple as that. When this affects 10k rep users, that's another  (maybe annoying) matter.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire `The question is not "why continue reading?" but "why do you want to decide in my place if I should stop reading?"` In your case, because an user with your rep has no **permission** to access that content anymore, so it's interrupted ASAP. *Should it be that way?* is another very different question.

Comment: @Daniel, I think that's the point of the question: Should I be allowed to *finish* reading if I was allowed to *start* reading. IMO Yes.

Comment: @alain In my opinion, **no**. It's been allowed in the past in many systems due technical limitations, caching, file already loaded from filesystem... But if there is not such limitations I dont know a reason (or a precedent) why the permissions shouldnt be enforced immediatly

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz As mentioned in my OP, I still can read it. It's cumbersome, but I still can. So the current solution solves nothing: it's just annoying. You want to force the removal of the post? What are we speaking about? Military secrets? Life or death stuff? Nope: just questions about code. So what's with the "*immediate*" enforcement you're speaking about?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Two things: **1)** in IT, the enforcement of a rule doesn't care about it being military secrets or kitty pictures. If and when it's inaccessible by you, it's inaccessible by you, save technical limitations. **2)** My argument was contructed over **meagar's comment**: `A 5k user isn't supposed to be able to see deleted content; they can't interact with it in any way. Reloading the page will result in a 404.` . If that affirmation is false (you say you can still see it jumping through some hoops), then **my whole argument is invalid** :)

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz The argument of immediate enforcement for resource access is raised only by you: meagar said that the immediate enforcement is for my own good (so I don't waste my time). His first and third comments all go in that way (if you include the whole comment, not the only part you want to quote). So... hum... is your whole argument invalid? You tell me ;)

Comment: Not sure if I should have posted it as an answer, but here is a screenshot of the message on a deleted post to illustrate the question (can't edit it) : http://i.imgur.com/iUUJ6yh.jpg (added obligatory red circle)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire The part I want to quote is the relevant part for my **2)** point. As for my **1)** point, (immediate enforcing) I don't think it's only made by me... I think it's a staple in IT security to check and restrict access *as soon as technologically viable*. if you `chmod`a file it doesn't wait until reboot to deny access. It does on next chance it got of checking permissions. Sure, in *ye olde times* that meant, in web context, until page reload, because *constant polling* just for that wouldn't be sane. It's not **THAT** important. But today AJAX and "server push" are so easy...

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz Well thank you for the comparison, it's a really nice one. I created a file on my Ubuntu system and opened it with some free editors (nano, vi, gedit, netbeans). Then, while open, I `chmod`-ed it, `chown`-ed it and I `rm`-ed it in a separate terminal. Result? In some editors, I get a notification. In others nothing happens. But no applications closed the file making it impossible for me to read it. So please, go and suggest a fix to all the text editors in that way if you're so convinced it should be done that way.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire haha, I somehow **knew** you would put that example, (my comparison wasn't perfect) that's why it's so important the ***as soon as technologically viable*** part. Obviously, the file is loaded in main memory but next time you open it through the FileSystem, it will revalidate them. It would be too slow, otherwise. *Impractical*. AJAX is not. But, anyways, I tried to explain my point once and again. If it still didn't get to you **a)** I'm failing to explain my point, **b)** you are failing to understand it or **c)** both, so... nevermind! ^^U (No hard feelings!)

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz you talk about this rule as if it were a law of nature, never to be changed by any living being.. But that's not the case here obviously. I think the discussion here is about requesting to *slightly* relax the rule for people that already started to read something. It has nothing to to with enforcement, it's about the rule itself.

Comment: What if the question was deleted because it contained offensive material? If it was something that you _didn't_ want to see I don't think we would be having the same discussion...

Comment: I agree with this request. As someone who is curious, likes to read things, and commits the time necessary to finish things that I start, I find it pretty rude to have an answer removed from in front of my face. Equivalent to reading a book and having the publisher rip it out of my hands because he didn't catch a typo or changed his mind about whether he liked the story.

Comment: @MacroMan I wouldn't know, 'cause I wouldn't have enough time to judge it...

Comment: @alain Sure rules can be changed, but here we are not discussing the rule itself (*which I haven't pronounced about*), but the enforcement of it. `slightly relax the rule for people that already started to read something` is a clear statement about how enforce (or apply) this rule, not about the rule itself. In any case, the creation of an addendum to the law to regulate its application (which would be, again, about the application of it). But that's may be just how I see it. If there's a consesus about the interpretation, the question could very well be about daisies and bees and I shut up xD

Comment: I'd liken that experience to losing a sneeze...

Comment: While we are discussing this, I'd say we should also consider deleted answers. It's the same concept after all.

Comment: You've been on stack exchange for over six years and this has happened exactly once? That doesn't seem very onerous.

Comment: @BryanOakley As others mentioned, this is a new feature.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: right, but the point still remains that it doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @BryanOakley Indeed, but the point also remains that it's annoying and *totally* counterintuitive when it does.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: I guess that depends on your own intuition. It happened to me once and I thought "great! I can stop reading". <shrug>

Answer (score 75):

Well, if the question gets closed, and especially if it gets deleted, that *should* be immediately signalled in a very conspicuous way, because there's normally a very good reason for it, and anyway it severely restricts your options for further interaction. To put it another way, any further time spent on it is nearly always simply wasted.

Still, I concur that even if you are shy of 10K, you should be able to easily acknowledge the change and assert that you want to read on anyway. Perhaps because there was actually something interesting, or you simply cannot stop yourself.

Comment: ...but if you are below 10k you are not **allowed** to see that content anymore, are you? So it should be inaccesible ASAP, it doesn't matter if you were allowed 10 seconds ago. We IT guys take restricting access to content very seriously, hehe

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz sure I can just shoot the messenger telling me I shouldn't do something. You've already given me the information and I want to keep it. It's just that running Wireshark 24/7 is probably an overkill.

Comment: @JanDvorak Who needs 10k when you have WireShark right :p

Comment: @alex anyone who wants to see questions deleted before they were interested in seeing them.

Comment: Just blocking ajax requests would be much easier I guess...

Comment: blocking ajax requests? So much work! Better just pull the internet cord/disable the WiFi adapter until you've finished reading! hahaha :P

Comment: Too much work. Just print to PDF and read it.

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz Yes. And people under 10k that somehow managed to finish reading just before the question got deleted should have their short-term memory wiped clean.

Comment: I saw one of these a few days ago (raised concerns with an answer then went to bed leaving the tab open) but just closed the tab since the answer ending up deleted didn't surprise me in the least.  I didn't look closely at the page first; would tampering with the http traffic itself be needed; or could I have just adblocked a this-was-deleted overlay div if I wanted to gawk a bit more before leaving.

Comment: @DanNeely: If you're curious, the code that adds the overlay can be found [here](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js) (Ctrl+F and search for `postDeleted`). The actual trigger event is sent via WebSockets (the same feed as used for notifications about new comments, answers, edits and votes). I already have code to intercept those WebSocket messages in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/q/4486), so it shouldn't be too hard to hack this UI into something more reader-friendly; the only question is exactly how it *should* behave in the various cases (deleted question vs. answer, <10k vs. >10k).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen just change the page background to red - set the exact same class to the question that deleted answers have.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's probably the right thing to do, although arguably, for 10k+ users, it really should refresh the post via Ajax so that you can see who deleted it (but that would again make the post text disappear if it was deleted as spam or offensive, so... some kind of a partial update?). And for <10k readers, the UI should probably be tweaked to disable comments and votes / flags, since those won't work for deleted posts. And there's the special case where you trigger the deletion yourself, which the current UI apparently handles (kind of suboptimally) by forcing an immediate page reload.

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz You've already sent the information, so whether or not access is restricted afterwards is a moot point in terms of security and permissions, and it should always be assumed that the content was completely received/read. Your comments make this sound like it's a major security vulnerability, but fail to notice that revoking access after the fact, itself, is a security vulnerability - and anything you do afterwards is *purely* cosmetic.

Answer (score 19):

Although I understand the general thought behind the overlay telling the post is deleted, it is impossible to read on now, especially when you have less than 10K reputation, which is not what the dialog is for.

To mitigate this, a simple overlay can be shown with a dismiss button. It fixes the issue for that 99% of the users that don't want to read on, and for the remaining 1% to keep reading.

Answer (score 1):

There should at least be a countdown time to deletion so that the reader can have time to copy and paste the question somewhere else. some of us when we try to answer some questions, we are also learning something new

Comment: Right, or you can at least learn *why* it was deleted.