# Bad User Experience when leaving a comment on a post and an OP deletes that post while writing out a comment

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, moderators

When I close questions, I tend to leave comments as to why.  Besides the "most people don't read the close reason" issue, it just helps let everyone else know exactly what I saw and exactly what they can do to have their post re-opened.

With the new "This Post has been deleted" text that shows up when the OP deletes their post, it seriously hurts this workflow.  Here's why:

1. Close question.
2. Type out detailed comment explaining how to get it re-opened.
3. OP deletes post.
4. Page interrupts my comment typing with this:

[image]

The end result is that I'm not able to save the comment, get it back, and refreshing the page causes me to lose the comment.

Feature Request(s):

1. Don't make the 'this post has been deleted' something that stops all text input, especially since moderators can leave comments on deleted posts.
2. Save content written in comment boxes to local storage until it's submitted, and fill it back in on page load.

Comment: Inspect element, delete :D At least for a temporary solution.

Comment: @TravisJ Yea; I tried that. I see the textarea but none of the text in it seems to show up either in the `innerHTML` or `innerText` attributes.

Comment: Can't you just type in it and use the interface as it would normally once the overlayed element is gone?

Comment: `textarea` values are under the `.value` property. Travis is suggesting deleting the "post has been deleted" message from the DOM.

Comment: Please, please please can we exempt mods from this one way or another. It's nice to know but don't mess up my workflow just for that! (Conversely in the flag queue itself where it would be really useful to know if a post has been deleted there after loading the list there's no indication without expanding each post individually)

Comment: It's not really clear what positive value this has for _anyone_ (cf. [Deleting a post should not interrupt my reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316996)) Interrupting the user when there's nothing they need to (or can) do, but when they _could have_ done some things if not interrupted, is pretty irritating.

Comment: Does it still matter when the OP decides to fall on his sword without your help??  Fwiw, this isn't very different from the experience SO users have when they are slaving away at an answer and the question gets deleted a second before they are ready to click the Post button :)

Comment: @HansPassant yes, because sometimes users delete their own posts and then Undelete them later. Whether or not that happens, I want there to be a record that a moderator was there and said something when making a unilateral action.

Comment: But then your comment surely no longer applies the edited post.  Good thing that got avoided, isn't it?

Comment: @HansPassant No one said anything about editing.

Comment: Well, of course there was someone.  Users delete a post to either leave it deleted or buy time to modify it.

Comment: @TravisJ Which popular browser for iOS or Android has "Inspect element, delete"?

Comment: @DamianYerrick Chrome does. You need a computer and a USB cable though: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: And you also have to pray that memory pressure doesn't cause Android to unload Chrome nor Chrome the page in question before you reach a computer on which you have permission to install a prerelease version of Chrome.

Comment: I don't like the new-ish "post has been deleted functionality". Didn't it used to do something else, less jarring/obvious?

Comment: @KevinB, It did nothing at all I believe, unless you interacted with the post (try to vote, add comment..), at which point it would tell you that you couldn't, because it was deleted. So what it does now is better IMO, just not really done right.

Comment: The part of this that has caught me is when typing a comment on another post that wasn't deleted, clicking that banner for a separate answer of course refreshes the page and loses my comment. To be fair, i was warned by the text, but... it happened anyway.

Comment: @Flexo: No!  If it's bad, it should be fixed **for everyone**.  Diamond mods have a different set of rules by design, but we shouldn't introduce gratuitous differences that accomplish nothing except making UX bad for others.

Comment: @JonasCz it did indeed do something... a banner alert would display across fixed position at top of viewport and that sure seemed a lot cleaner than new overlay. Really annoying even just reading something and the overlay appears

Comment: Notice that if you open up the dom inspector, you can remove the overlay, and the reduced opacity setting for the post in question. Then you have the post in all it's glory, but you still cannot submit the comment. The next time I see it, I'll make up a userscript which adds a button to remove the overlay and restore the opacity, then post that here as an answer.

Comment: +1 I was responding to a user's rude comments telling me to "go away if I didn't care about his problem".  I had crafted an answer about how I cared deeply about the site's quality but before I could post the OP deleted the question.

Comment: Why do you need a comment's text anyway? If the post has been deleted, it's of no use anymore, is it?

Comment: Aren't we letting ego get in the way of the simple realization that if the OP has deleted their post, it's already "game over". Why would you worry about spending more time on that? Just move on.

Comment: @TimLong if we didn't get a lot of questions that ask "why did a moderator unilaterally close my post", I might agree with you.

Answer (score 14):

An easy fix would be to allow certain activity such as comments on an deleted answer for some reasonable period of time, like 15 minutes to an hour or whatever. Those who started editing a comment while the post was still open for commenting then have a reasonable shot at completing it---provided they don't walk away from the browser for half a day and then continue typing.